# Create Reoccurring Outlook Appointment Programmatically

Tags: c#, outlook, telerik

I'm currently using telerik Schedule View which comes with an appointment creator and an optional occurrence reminder. I was successfully able to programmatically save the appointment created in the schedule view to my outlook using the code below.

```
_Application olApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
_AppointmentItem apt = (_AppointmentItem) olApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
// set some properties
apt.Subject = item.Subject;
apt.Body = item.Body;
apt.Location = item.Location;                     //Set the location
apt.Start = item.Start;                           //Set the start date 
apt.End = item.End;                               //End date 
apt.ReminderSet = true;                           //Set the reminder
apt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15;              //Reminder time
apt.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceNormal; //Appointment importance
apt.BusyStatus = OlBusyStatus.olFree;             //Busy status
apt.Close(OlInspectorClose.olSave);
```

I would now like to expand and also save the reoccurence rule but I am not sure how to do that for the _AppointmentItem. Telerik's Appointment has a reoccurence rule but what properties of _AppointmentItem should be set? It should be something along side the pseudoCode below

```
apt.[..Frequency] = item.RecurrenceRule.Pattern.Frequency  
apt.[..MonthOfTheYear] = item.RecurrenceRule.Pattern.MonthOfYear;
```

Any tips or suggestions to creating Appointments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with MAPI?

Comment: Hi @DmitryStreblechenko Updated Title, sorry about confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Recurence Rules as explained [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/scheduler/recurrence-editor/server-side-programming/populating-the-recurrence-rule).
Sample:

```
RecurrenceRange range = new RecurrenceRange();
range.Start = DateTime.Now;
range.EventDuration = new Timespan(...);
range.MaxOccurrences = 3;
RecurrenceRule newDayly = new DailyRecurrenceRule(interval, range);
```

You can attach a rule directly to a "telerik" Appointment:

```
Appointment newAppointment = new Appointment();
newAppointment.RecurrenceRule = newDayly.ToString();
```

I think your questions is about to convert "Outlook" Recurrences to Telerik Recurrences...

Telerik got a sample for [RadScheduler with EWS integration](https://github.com/telerik/aspnet-sdk/tree/master/Scheduler/ExchangeCalendarSync), there you can have a look, how this will work. Here you find the [implementation of the Provider](https://github.com/telerik/aspnet-sdk/blob/master/Scheduler/ExchangeCalendarSync/App_Code/Exchange/ExchangeSchedulerProvider.cs). This should give you an idea how it works.

Comment: Hi, that's how to apply a recurrence rule to an appointment. But I already have a "telerik" appointment with a recurrence rule to an outlook _AppointmentItem

Comment: Please see the link implementation of the provider